# Mongodb $nin not working with nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I can't make $nin work with nested arrays, can you guys spot any issue with this query?
I'm basically trying to update the status of every document under items to "closed" in case their hash field is not in a list of hashes provided.

```
db.getCollection('projects').update({
    name: 'test',
    'issues.hash': { $nin: [
                    '8ff28fcc9cbf10c9b690bb331e5609efbd3c526be4f536ebca02cc51bd63eac7',
                    'd5368ad5658ec11103796255d127d26da7f3324cdedbd124bdd5db50812d588e',
                    '37298229097785ebc9d419cc1a3f13e0d090a15ceb9a8e6bea3505366902556d',
                    'fad290f2ddd0e097e4098c3b2c3d65611406cf208a3f86924d45c7736393b44b'
                ]}

    }, 
    {
        $set: { "issues.$.status": "closed" }
    }
)
```

This is the data:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("611bb4d2ee06769a5f6d906d"),
    "name" : "test",
    "issues" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("611bb4d20b2fb200167aa588"),
            "status" : "open",
            "hash" : "8ff28fcc9cbf10c9b690bb331e5609efbd3c526be4f536ebca02cc51bd63eac7"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("611bb4d20b2fb200167aa589"),
            "status" : "open",
            "hash" : "3b83e469049e46b16d3471a188d3f5e3ddbf6b296995a71765bbf17b7289e6ea"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("611bb4d20b2fb200167aa58a"),
            "status" : "open",
            "hash" : "bef5f50628b669b9930b89cdc040361b9c8cc2b4aab3c2059c171786d38d507e"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("611bb4d20b2fb200167aa58b"),
            "status" : "open",
            "hash" : "1b4a91eb5de97d6ad7493b6e1ffa48a2a648084b4af7b37916c723533a07c37c"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("611bb4d20b2fb200167aa58c"),
            "status" : "open",
            "hash" : "bb64ba7b2612856dcd95c3ac2fad3f7368e5d463168545b12f4c869af56b55b7"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("611bb4d20b2fb200167aa58d"),
            "status" : "open",
            "hash" : "1d5fc04739b10414dea8d327998df4f200f47ce57da243bd578d4ae102f2d670"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("611bb4d20b2fb200167aa58e"),
            "status" : "open",
            "hash" : "d5368ad5658ec11103796255d127d26da7f3324cdedbd124bdd5db50812d588e"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("611bb4d20b2fb200167aa58f"),
            "status" : "open",
            "hash" : "37298229097785ebc9d419cc1a3f13e0d090a15ceb9a8e6bea3505366902556d"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("611bb4d20b2fb200167aa590"),
            "status" : "open",
            "hash" : "fad290f2ddd0e097e4098c3b2c3d65611406cf208a3f86924d45c7736393b44b"
        }
    ]
}
```

And the is my result:

```
Updated 0 record(s) in 12ms
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uQO2Ch6397A) what are you looking for? If it works for you I can add an answer to explain better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [`arrayFilters`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) in this way:

```
db.collection.update({
  "name": "test"
},
{
  "$set": {
    "issues.$[element].status": "closed"
  }
},
{
  "arrayFilters": [
    {
      "element.hash": {
        "$nin": [
          "8ff28fcc9cbf10c9b690bb331e5609efbd3c526be4f536ebca02cc51bd63eac7",
          "d5368ad5658ec11103796255d127d26da7f3324cdedbd124bdd5db50812d588e",
          "37298229097785ebc9d419cc1a3f13e0d090a15ceb9a8e6bea3505366902556d",
          "fad290f2ddd0e097e4098c3b2c3d65611406cf208a3f86924d45c7736393b44b"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/npqqCRBC3wR).

Note that `update` query has the format: `update(query, update, options)` (Check the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/)).

So with your `find` query mongo doesn't find anything. Check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jQQhxgFijX0) example.

This is why you are telling mongo: "Give me a DOCUMENT where name is test and `issues` array NOT contains a field called `hash` with these values".

So, as mongo search by the whole document, there is no any document where `hash` value is not on the `$nin` array.

As another example to exaplain better: Check [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Qnvuty4lfca) where `hash` value is 1. In this case, `find` query works because it matches two conditions:

- There is a field `name` with value `test`
- There is not any field `hash` into `issues` with values into `$nin` array.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#std-label-update-array-filters), like this:

```
db.collection.update({
  "name": "test"
},
{
  "$set": {
    "issues.$[elem].status": "closed"
  }
},
{
  "multi": true,
  "arrayFilters": [
    {
      "elem.hash": {
        "$nin": [
          "8ff28fcc9cbf10c9b690bb331e5609efbd3c526be4f536ebca02cc51bd63eac7",
          "d5368ad5658ec11103796255d127d26da7f3324cdedbd124bdd5db50812d588e",
          "37298229097785ebc9d419cc1a3f13e0d090a15ceb9a8e6bea3505366902556d",
          "fad290f2ddd0e097e4098c3b2c3d65611406cf208a3f86924d45c7736393b44b"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Here is the working example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/8wZkmlBgKiq